# python speed calculation optimisation

Tags: python, calculation

I have a script with two lists. One list has measured distances and the other has spend time. I then calculate max speed ether at  certain distances or for certain time window. For example I calculate max speed in two seconds period, 10s period.... and max speed at 100 meters, 1 km....

So i first do for loop for each measurement and in that loop for x i find end point which is y meters or y seconds away from point x and then calculate traveled distance and spend time and then calculate speed.

This works fine but when there is a lot of data in lists it takes quite some time for calculations to complete. When i try the same in some closed sourced applications calculations are done in matter of seconds while my script sometimes takes minutes to  calculate. Any idea how i could speed up things ?

```
distance=[1,2,6,8,13,15,18,24,27,34,37,38,44,47,48,49]
time=[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18]


def calculate(arr,unit,type):
    pointer=-1
    max=0
    for xy in arr:
        pointer+=1
        try:        
            if type=='distance':
                 nxt=next(x[0] for x in enumerate(distance) if x[1] > (distance[pointer]+unit))
            else:
                 nxt=next(x[0] for x in enumerate(time) if x[1] > (time[pointer]+unit))

            vald=distance[nxt]-distance[pointer]
            valc=time[nxt]-time[pointer]
            value=round((vald/valc)*1.94384449,2)

            if value > max and value < 45:
                 max=value
        except:
            pass

        return(max)

print(calculate(distance,2,"time"))
print(calculate(distance,10,"time"))
print(calculate(distance,10,"distance"))
```

Comment: In the case your time window is smaller than the difference in the time of the observations, what is your expected behaviour? I.e. if you wanted to get the best speed every 2 seconds of times `[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9]`, `1` up to `6` is obvious, as you can create a subarray sum of 2. `6` and `9` have 3 seconds however. Do you want to assume the velocity is constant between `6` and `9` and just multiply the speed by `2/3`? Or discard that period entirely as you cannot guarantee the 2-second-window speed?

Comment: You don't seem to be using the `arr` argument of the calculate function in any meaningful way

Comment: One way to speed up the calculation is to implement a [segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree)

Comment: I will take a look if i can find the rules for measurements. Let say i have track with distance of 30km and I am calculating the fastest 100m. If i split the track in segments of 100m that would be only 300 segments and calculations would be supper fast since my calculation is done so that thousands of segments are used. My method takes 1 point calculates the next one that is 100m away, then takes the second point which is just few meters away from first and again calculate 100m etc.

Comment: I tried splinting data in segments and not calculate segments for each point. Results are quite similar, results are slightly lower as expected but not much. There is however a big sped improvement. What take 24s before is now done in 4.

Comment: immediately you should be using vectorised processes (`list` -> `numpy.array`). This is why: https://youtu.be/e1zRI46ZSUo